# Who in history coined the term "character" of a group and why is it called so?

Tags: terminology

I first read the term in an introduction of Fourier transform on locally compact groups. In this article on [Character of a group](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Character_of_a_group) from Encyclopedia of Mathematics, a *character of a group* is defined as a homomorphism of the given group into some standard Abelian group $A$. It is said that

> The concept of a character of a group was originally introduced for finite groups $G$ with $A=T:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ (in this case every character $G\to \mathbb{C}^*$ takes values in $T$).

Who in history coined the term "character" of a group and why is it called so?

Comment: Check *Vorlesungen über Zahlentheorie* on Google books  By Peter Gustav Lejeune Dirichlet (1894). He introduced the term *character* and *class* which is now used group theory. Search the word "Charaktere" pg 612. I used Deepl.com to translate.

Comment: @M.Farooq：Thanks for that. There is also an English edition: https://books.google.ca/books/about/Lectures_on_Number_Theory.html?id=8h8aWmnp1k8C&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With credit to @ConsigliereZARF for helpful comments and references. The earliest definition of group character ("*Charakter*") for Abelian groups is likely due to Weber (1881-2), and it was generalized to general groups by Frobenius (1896). According to [Mackey's survey Harmonic analysis as the exploitation of symmetry](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1980-03-01/S0273-0979-1980-14783-7/home.html):

> "*In 1881 Weber defined a character of a finite commutative group $G$ to be a complex valued function $\chi$ on $G$ such that $\chi(xy) = \chi(x)\chi(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $G$. This definition was an abstract generalization of one given three years earlier by Dedekind in connection with his work on algebraic number theory, which was inspired in turn by early work of Gauss and Dirichlet (see sections 6 and 12). While Weber's definition makes sense for arbitrary finite groups, it is more or less vacuous except insofar as the group has commutative aspects. Specifically, every character is identically one on the commutator
>   subgroup and consequently the only characters not identically one are
>   derived trivially from characters of commutative quotient groups.*
>
> *Group
>   theory acquired a powerful new tool that was soon to become almost indispensable
>   when G. Frobenius (1849-1917) published a paper in 1896 showing
>   that there is a natural generalization of the character notion that involves
>   the whole group $G$ in a significant and interesting way—even when $G$ is
>   non-commutative.*"

Mackey appears to refer to Weber's [*Beweis des Satzes, dass jede eigentlich primitive quadratische Form unendlich viele Primzahlen darzustellen fähig ist* (1882)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01443599), where he generalizes Dirichlet's prime number theorem. Weber introduces the character using a basis of Abelian group and remarks that it always satisfies the multiplicative property. In a footnote he credits [Dedekind's Supplement XI to the third edition of Dirichlet's *Vorlesungen über Zahlentheorie* (1879), p. 581](https://archive.org/details/vorlesungenberz01dirigoog/page/n604/mode/2up).

Dirichlet uses the word "*Charaktere*" throughout [*Vorlesungen über Zahlentheorie*](https://archive.org/details/vorlesungenberz02dirigoog/page/n636/mode/2up), the earliest on p.77 in connection with [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol), and then expands the use of the name (p. 316). [Dirichlet's characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character#Dirichlet_characters) are not quite group characters, and the notion of a group was not in place at the time of Gauss's or Dirichlet's writing. However,  concerning Gauss's "total character" of a quadratic form from *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae* (1801), Mackey writes:

> "*The word character as used today stems directly from Gauss's use of the
>   term in his theory of binary quadratic forms... Dedekind makes the same definition for the special case of the ideal class group
>   of an algebraic number field. As Dedekind himself had pointed out earlier,
>   the ideal class group is a generalization of Gauss's group of equivalence
>   classes of binary quadratic forms. Dedekind's mode of expression is such as
>   to make it clear that he regards his definition as a generalization of that of
>   Gauss.*"

Before Gauss, quadratic characters, later generalized by Jacobi and Dirichlet, appear in   Legendre's [*Essai sur la theorie des nombres* (1798)](https://archive.org/details/essaisurlathor00lege/page/n6/mode/2up). Introducing the quadratic character symbol, he simply wrote:

> "*As the quantities analogous to $N^{\frac{c-1}2}$ will frequently appear in the course of our research, we will use the abbreviated **character** $\left(\frac{N}{c}\right)$ to express the residue from dividing $N^{\frac{c-1}2}$ by $c$; the residue which, according to what we have just seen, can only be $+1$ or $-1$*."[ See [Cajori, History of Mathematical Notation, p.30](https://archive.org/details/AHistoryOfMathematicalNotationVolII/page/n53/mode/2up)]

So to him "character" meant nothing more than "symbol". Whether this is where Gauss took the word from is unclear, Mackey says that large parts of *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae* were written before Legendre's *Essai* was published, but Gauss "*acknowledges that he was inspired to study quadratic forms by the work of Lagrange and Legendre*". Legendre divided classes of forms into cosets that Gauss called genera, and forms were said to be in the same genus if they had the same "total character", a system of $+1$s and $-1$s canonically associated to them. Each $\pm1$ was produced by a function on forms what we today call a group character.

Comment: **[No](//hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11057/who-discovered-the-covering-homomorphism-between-su2-and-so3/11060#comment20134_11058).** The answer is well known to be Gauß (1801).

Comment: @Mars You just accepted a wrong answer. See Mackey [1980](//doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-1980-14783-7), pp. 555–556, 598.

Comment: @ConsigliereZARF: thanks for the link. The most relevant text I found is *"It turns out that Gauss's characters are characters in the
modern sense for the finite commutative group in question."*, *"The word character as used today stems directly from Gauss's use of the
term in his theory of binary quadratic forms."* and *"Characters and Fourier analysis on finite commutative groups occur implicitly in other parts of Gauss's work. "*

Comment: @ConsigliereZARF: it seems that the term had evolved a bit since Gauss.

Comment: I think Mackey refers to [Weber's Beweis des Satzes, p. 307-8](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01443599), where he indeed introduces characters in group theoretic terminology with reference to Dedekind's Supplement XI to the third edition of Dirichlet's *Vorlesungen über Zahlentheorie* (1879). This is earlier than Miller's references, and might be the earliest occurrence of group character proper. I will change the answer accordingly.

Comment: @ConsigliereZARF I'll change to what you'd prefer. I am going to fix the phase space similarly.

Comment: @ConsigliereZARF It's the end of semester, not too much time. I still think it would be better if you posted the answers directly.

Comment: I did, to the OP. We've had that conversation, it's not about what any person does. Correcting anonymous falsehoods is no one's idea of fun, nor would contributing to a site that increasingly does more harm than good be very moral. That is why, I believe, the manpower to correctly answer and moderate is at MO and not here. Not enough time for due diligence?

Comment: @ConsigliereZARF The path to the truth is through correcting falsehoods. Miller's site (which is probably more frequented than hsm) has inaccurate/incomplete information on character, as does Nolte's published article on phase space. Alternative answers and open editing are there to flush out mistakes over time when they are noticed. But this is a volunteer site, like Wikipedia, not a refereed publication with paid editors for due diligence. To me, it does more good than harm despite resource limitations and mistakes, but we disagree on that obviously.

Comment: Why cut and paste Miller or Nolte into a "narrative", then? The path to the truth is not through that, but through finding primary sources and admitting when one doesn't know. MO is just as volunteer but works — thanks to no small feat of good management.

Comment: @ConsigliereZARF Because due to time and resource limitations volunteer sites mostly rely on secondary sources, primary research is the day job of their authors and publishers. Their mistakes are reflected here, and corrected as time and enthusiasm permit. And most users asking questions here have bigger gaps in understanding history than misplaced dates of "first" occurrences, so even "wrong" answers give them something, which is why it feels worthwhile to me. MO is not a relevant model, history isn't mathematics. In any case, I am glad you chose to contribute in your own way.

Comment: History of mathematics participates of both. Anyway, 1) where are the historians? 2) let's not make it (again) about assimilating any one person 3) how about "this replaces a previously erroneous answer"?